# Display image above the shape at Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating a website that was able to display shapes and colors in the canvas, my problem is the picture won't show up anymore.

Here's my html sample:

```
    // These are my choices for the first step in designing.
    <input type="radio" id="shape_1" name="shape" onchange="display()" /> circle 
    <input type="radio" id="shape_2" name="shape" onchange="display()" /> rectangle 
    //2nd step, choose color
    <input type="radio" id="color_1" name="color" onchange="display()" /> RED  
   //3rd step, choose image
   <select name="picture" id="picture_display" onchange="display()" />
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="orange">Orange</option>

<canvas id="displaycanvas" height="450px" width="820px" style="position:absolute;"> </canvas>
```

for my JS (separate):

```
function display() { //working fine
  var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycanvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  function Choices() { //working fine too...
    if (document.getElementById('color_1').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('shape_1').checked) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.stroke();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('shape_2').checked) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100);
      context.stroke();
    }
  }

  function Picture() { //these part it won't work, I've tried to do something like this.
    if (document.getElementById('picture_display').value == 'apple') {
      document.getElementById('displaycanvas').src = 'http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Apple_Logo_Png_04.png';
    }
    if (document.getElementById('picture_display').value == 'orange') {
      document.getElementById('displaycanvas').src = 'http://dailyrindblog.com/styleguide/web_version/logo_fruit.png';
    }
  }
}
```

I want the image will be above for the first 2 steps but *doesn't go beyond either those given shapes* (if possible, if its not it's fine). Anything I simply missed or change it all? **Thank you so much in advance!**

For the **dragging code** you can suggest some links that is applicable to this one.

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log)

Comment: Yes, but nothing. It simply works fine but ain't displaying the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a reference to the context, then load image object and when done draw the image on the context

```
function Picture() { 
      var e = document.getElementById("picture_display");
      var selValue1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

      var context = document.getElementById('displaycanvas').getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };

    if (selValue1 === 'apple') {
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Apple_Logo_Png_04.png';
    }
    if (selValue1 === 'orange') {
      imageObj.src = 'http://dailyrindblog.com/styleguide/web_version/logo_fruit.png';
    }
  }
```